# awk find out how many times columns two and three equal specific word

Tags: awk

Lets say I have a names.txt file with the following

```
Bob Billy Billy
Bob Billy Joe
Bob Billy Billy
Joe Billy Billy
```

and using awk I want to find out how many times $2 = Billy while $3 = Billy. In this case my desired output would be 3 times.

Also, I'm testing this on a mac if that matters.

Comment: You have more than one file or that is you only input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to test `$2==$3` then test that one of those equals `"Billy"`. Increment a counter and then print the result at the end:

```
$ awk '$2==$3 && $2=="Billy"{cnt++} END{print cnt+0}' names.txt
3
```

Or, you could almost write just what you said:

```
$ awk '$2=="Billy" && $3=="Billy" {cnt++} END{print cnt+0}' names.txt
3
```

And if you want to use a variable so you don't need to type it several times:

```
$ awk -v name='Billy' '$2==name && $3==name {cnt++} 
                       END{printf "Found \"%s\" %d times\n", name, cnt+0}' names.txt
Found "Billy" 3 times
```

Or, you could collect them all up and report what was found:

```
$ awk '{cnts[$2 "," $3]++}
        END{for (e in cnts) print e ": " cnts[e]}' names.txt
Billy,Billy: 3
Billy,Joe: 1
```

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks for the constructive comments. Edits made.

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider use `grep` to do that,

```
$ grep -c "\sBilly\sBilly" name.txt
3
```

`-c`: print  a count of matching lines